# C/C++ application cannot create connections using multiple network interfaces on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: c, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, network-programming

Summary:

I have an AWS instance with multiple network interfaces. My C/C++ application is able to make connections using one interface, but as soon as I try a 2nd/3rd, the code hangs on `::connect()`.

Details:

I created `N` elastic IPs, created `N` network interfaces, associated each elastic IP with one network interface and associated all the interfaces to my instance.

I wrote a C/C++ function which uses `ip -4 -brief address show` to return all Ethernet interface names. It checks whether the interface name begins with `eth` or `en`.

I create a socket, choose one of the interface names and use `setsockopt` to set the interface:

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, interface_name, strlen(interface_name));
```

Everything works fine if I stick to one network interface. However, as soon as I try to use a 2nd/3rd... interface the code hangs on `::connect()`.

I've never used multiple interfaces before, so I'm unsure if this is a C/C++, Linux or AWS Elastic IP issue?

As a hack I changed my function getting the interface names to only return one and everything works fine.

Does anyone know if additional work needs to be done on Linux (or AWS) to allow using multiple interfaces?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04